# Salvar imagem dentro de um projeto C#

Tags: c#, io

Eu estou conseguindo salvar a imagem dentro do sistema operacional Windows utilizando o código abaixo;

```
private static String CAMINHO_IMAGEM = "C://temp//Image.png";

public void capturaTela() {
            Screenshot imagem = ((ITakesScreenshot)getDriver()).GetScreenshot();
            string dataHora = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"));
            String telaCapturada = CAMINHO_IMAGEM + "telaCapturada" + "_" + dataHora + ".png";
            imagem.SaveAsFile(telaCapturada, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
        }
```

O que esse método faz é tirar uma foto da tela do sistema e salva a imagem no `C://temp//`

Porém eu preciso mesmo é salvar a imagem dentro de um projeto C# Alguém teria uma sugestão como eu poderia fazer isso?

Esse algoritmo abaixo é do Java. ele consegue salvar dentro do Path do projeto, mas eu preciso fazer algo semelhante em C#

```
public void finalizarTestes() throws IOException {
        TakesScreenshot takesScreenshot = (TakesScreenshot) getDriver();
        File arquivo = takesScreenshot.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(arquivo, new File(
                "target" + File.separator + "screenshot" + File.separator + testName.getMethodName() + ".jpg"));
    }
```

Na verdade eu queria salvar dentro desse diretório

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não bastaria altera o valor de `CAMINHO_IMAGEM`?

Comment: O que seria salvar "dentro de um projeto C#"? Seria salvar na mesma pasta do executável?

Comment: Olá @Woss Se eu colocar o caminho estático do projeto C# não iria adiantar porque esse projeto irá ser alocado no servidor e muito provavelmente o caminho será diferente. É necessário salva dentro  do Path do projeto.

Comment: E se colocar um caminho relativo ao invés de absoluto?

Comment: O ideal seria pegar o caminho relativo, mas eu não sei fazer isso.

Comment: `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory` dá a pasta do teu executável

Comment: @wladyband use o `System.IO.Path.Combine` para concatenar caminhos.

Comment: Você não estaria querendo embutir uma imagem como recurso do projeto? Veja [Criar arquivos de recurso para aplicativos .NET](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/core/extensions/create-resource-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se o problema é o caminho até o teu executável para salvar o arquivo, tu poderias pegar ele nessa propriedade:

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory
```

Ou talvez

```
Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location
```

Ou, ainda:

```
System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(
    System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().CodeBase)
```

Ou, se tu estiveres usando um projeto Windows Forms

```
Application.StartupPath;
```

Comment: eu tentei dessa forma mas não funcionou private static String CAMINHO_IMAGEM = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;

Comment: Coloquei uma segunda opção. Testa aí

Comment: quero agradecer por tentado me ajudar. Sou muito grato.

Answer (score 0):

Fiquei quebrando a cabeça o dia inteiro e conseguir encontrar minha solução e resolvi postar aqui a resposta para ajudar a comunidade.

```
  private static String CAMINHO_IMAGEM = @"evidencias\..\..\";

    public void capturaTelaErro()
    {
        var fullpath = Path.GetFullPath(CAMINHO_IMAGEM);

        Screenshot imagem = ((ITakesScreenshot)getDriver()).GetScreenshot();
        string dataHora = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss", CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("pt-BR"));
        String telaCapturada = fullpath + "telaCapturada" + "_" + dataHora + ".png";
        String telaCapturadaPDF = dataHora + ".pdf";
        imagem.SaveAsFile(telaCapturada, ScreenshotImageFormat.Png);
        
    }
```